# Vertical center/change calculated height react-slick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-slick

I am trying to find a way to vertically center or otherwise add space to my react-slick slider so that I can show a box-shadow when slides are hovered over. Currently it seems the height is being automatically calculated and the `slick-list` wrapper has an inline style of the calculated height of the slides.

Is there any way for me to override or otherwise get around the inline height or `overflow:hidden` on `slick-list` being set so I can show my box shadow?

current (box shadow turned red for better visibility):
[image: Screenshot of cut off box shadow]

desired would be something closer to this, where you can see the bottom of the drop shadow. I got this by manually editing the height in my browser:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but are you not able to add some padding to each slide? Also try setting the height you want for .slick-list, make your slides have `height: 100%;` and then they should all have the height of the parent (.slick-list).

If you want to center the slides within the parent, make the parent a `display: flex;` and add `align-content: center;`

If that's not what you're looking for, post screenshots and the code you have.

Comment: Added photos and updated my question for hopefully better clarity

Comment: I'm currently using react-slick in a project and setting a fixed height for the slides causes .slick-slider to have the height of the longest slide.
If not, try adding some margin-bottom to your slides, it should also do the trick.

Comment: margin-bottom didn't make any space between the slide container and the slides but I used relative position on `.slick-track` and that helped, the box-shadow is still slightly cut off but its working better than before